# Conflicting NetworkPolicies in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Suppose I have 2 network policies, for nodes matching labels "app=database". Suppose:

- First policy has rules that block all ingress traffic.
- Second policy has a rule allows ingress traffic on port 5660.

Even though this is a simple example, how does kubernetes decides which rule wins?
In more complex scenarios with several overlapping rules maybe covering similar pods, how would this be managed? E.g.: can we define priorities in Network policies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubernetes network policies right now does not allow *deny* policies. There are only *allow* policies. You basically put together all the allowed policies for the pod to get the allowed connections.

When there are one or more network policies on a pod, then all the connections   *allowed by at least one of the network policies*, will be allowed.

So how does the default deny works. It just tells that the allowed connections are none.

A more detailed explanation is available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#isolated-and-non-isolated-pods).

Answer (score 0):

Actually that depends on how your network policy plugin implements it. Currently there's also no way for us to define priorities. If you indeed have conflicting rule, then you made a mistake. You should try to apply policies without conflicting rules.